# Xamarin in Visual Studio install issues: The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly, "SetSite failed for package"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Suffering from all of:

"The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly"

"SetSite failed for package" (in Visual Studio's ActivityLog.xml)

"LegacySitePackage failed for package" (in Visual Studio's ActivityLog.xml)

Resolution of such supposedly resolved by uninstall and reinstall of Xamarin as per this article: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/

However, I have followed ALL instructions, including creating a new windows user (at the very bottom). Problem is persisting, not resolved.

I am at a bit of a loss. Any community help/ideas would be amazingly appreciated! Thanks much!

Comment: Can you try deleting the ComponentModelCache folder at: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` . Replace "14.0" with "12.0" if using VS 2013.

Comment: any resolution to this?

Comment: try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167176/3270038](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167176/3270038)